# How to read and write DataFrame from Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, parquet

I need to save DataFrame in CSV or parquet format (as a single file) and then open it again. The amount of data will not exceed 60Mb, so a single file is reasonable solution. This simple task provides me a lot of headache... This is what I tried:

To read the file if it exists:

```
df = sqlContext
               .read.parquet("s3n://bucket/myTest.parquet")
               .toDF("key", "value", "date", "qty")
```

To write the file:

```
df.write.parquet("s3n://bucket/myTest.parquet")
```

This does not work because:

1) `write` creates the folder `myTest.parquet` with hadoopish files that later I cannot read with `.read.parquet("s3n://bucket/myTest.parquet")`. In fact I don't care about multiple hadoopish files, unless I can later read them easily into DataFrame. Is it possible?

2) I am always working with the same file `myTest.parquet` that I am updating and overwriting in S3. It tells me that the file cannot be saved because it already exists.

So, can someone indicate me a right way to do the read/write loop? The file format doesn't matter for me (csv,parquet,csv,hadoopish files) unleass I can make the read and write loop.

Comment: Have you seen the [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your DataFrame with `saveAsTable("TableName")` and read it with `table("TableName")`. And the location can be set by `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`. And you can overwrite a file with `mode(SaveMode.Ignore)`. You can [read](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#saving-to-persistent-tables) here more from the official documentation.

In Java it would look like this:

```
SparkSession spark = ...
spark.conf().set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:9000/tables");
Dataset<Row> data = ...
data.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("TableName");
```

Now you can read from the Data with:

```
spark.read().table("TableName");
```

Comment: May I ask you to give an example?

Comment: Edited my answer. Sry my example is in Java, because I am not very good in Scala. Do you use Spark 2.x.x? As far as I know there is no SparkSession, but you should be able to do it with SparkContext.

Comment: I use Spark 1.6.2, because Spark 2.0.0 is currently not advisable for the production.